# Botón se Bloquea después de Actualizar la tabla

Tags: php, javascript

Al hacer click en el botón editar, estoy mostrando un modal con los datos de la fila seleccionada, modifico sus datos y se guardan correctamente. Posteriormente la tabla se actualiza, sin embargo el botón editar, no llama al modal si hago click en cualquiera de las filas de la tabla, ¿ Por que sucede esto?¿Como puedo corregirlo?

PD: btn_editar es el boton del modal que clikeo para guardar los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">   


$(document).ready(function() {   


 $(".editar").click(function(){

    $("#modal_editar").modal('show');


 });


$("#btn_editar").click(function(){

var id_tip = $("#id_tip").val();
var id_suc = $("#id_suc").val();
var estado = $("#estado").val();
var rut_usu = $("#rut_usu").val();

$.ajax({

 url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "C_Administrar_Usuarios/editar_usuario/",
 type: 'post',
 data: { "id_tip": id_tip, "id_suc": id_suc, "estado" : estado , "rut_usu" : rut_usu},

 success: function(response){ 

       $("#modal_editar").modal('hide');

       $("#modal_confirmar").modal('show');

       $("#tabla_usuarios").load(location.href+" #tabla_usuarios>*","");

    }

  });

 }); 

});

</script>
```

Mi tabla la estoy mostrando de la siguiente forma

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div >
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>Lista de Usuarios</h4>


      </div>


      <div class="panel-body">
        <?php
          $options = array(
                    '5'  => '5',
                    '10'    => '10'
                  );

          $selected = "5";
          if ($this->session->userdata("cantidad")) {
            $selected = $this->session->userdata("cantidad");
          }
        ?>
        <p><strong>Mostrar por : </strong><?php  echo form_dropdown('cantidad', $options,$selected)?></p>
        <table class="table table-bordered" >
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Rut</th>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Apellido Pat.</th>
              <th>Apellido Mat.</th>
              <th>Perfil</th>
              <th>Sucursal</th>
              <th>Estado</th>
              <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="tabla_usuarios">
            <?php foreach ($usuarios as $usuario) { ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $usuario->rut_usu;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $usuario->pnombre;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $usuario->apellido_pa;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $usuario->apellido_ma;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $usuario->descripcion_tip;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $usuario->nombre_suc;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $usuario->estado;?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<button class='editar' onclick=\"

        $('#rut_usu').val('$usuario->rut_usu');\n
        $('#id_tip').val('$usuario->id_tip');\n
        $('#pnombre').val('$usuario->pnombre');\n
        $('#snombre').val('$usuario->snombre');\n
        $('#id_suc').val('$usuario->id_suc');\n
        $('#apellido_pa').val('$usuario->apellido_pa');\n
        $('#apellido_ma').val('$usuario->apellido_ma');\n
        $('#estado').val('$usuario->estado');


        \" rut_usu='$usuario->rut_usu' id_tip='$usuario->id_tip' estado='$usuario->estado' pnombre='$usuario->pnombre' snombre='$usuario->snombre'apellido_pa='$usuario->apellido_pa' apellido_ma='$usuario->apellido_ma' class='btn btn-sm btn-default modificar' >Editar<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button>" ;?></td>
              </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="text-center">
          <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que es lo que pasa, podrías explicarme mejor ?

Comment: Tengo un foreach que muestra los datos desde mi base de datos, pero en el foreach también se muestra un botón con la clase editar, al hacer click en ese botón , se abre un modal en el que modifico los datos y los guardo. La tabla se actualiza y hasta allí todo ok. Pero si trato de hacer click en el botón editar de la tabla nuevamente(el que tiene la clase editar), después de que esta se haya actualizado, el botón no abre el modal.

Comment: Intenta cambiando esto `$(".editar").click(function(){` por esto `$(document).on("click", ".editar", function(){`

Comment: Funciono Perfecto, muchas gracias, ¿podrías colocarlo como respuesta para aceptarla?

Comment: Claro, ya te la publico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que cuando actualizas tu tabla los botones `.editar` ya no son reconocidos como elementos del DOM por que el JavaScript ya había sido cargado anteriormente y no hizo lectura de ellos.

Para que los botones sigan siendo reconocidos y puedan ejecutar el evento simplemente debes cambiar el selector de la siguiente forma:

```
$(document).on("click", ".editar", function(){
    ...
})
```